# Trying to insert delimiter into a text document

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to place a vertical bar at certain points in each line of a text file. My code is pretty straightforward I'm pretty sure...but when i try running it nothing happens. I don't even get an error. The file that it is supposed to write to just remains a blank text file

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

arrCommas =  Array(10,14,21,24,39,43,46,61,72,79,82,85,88,91,94,97,101,142,173,189,192,198,205,211,218,222,229,236,240)

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\SQL DATA FILES\MBS Stats\mbsedited\mbsfact102013_linebreaks.txt", ForReading)

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
strLine = objFile.ReadLine
intLength = Len(strLine)
For Each strComma in arrCommas
    strLine = Left(strLine, strComma - 1) + "|" + Mid(strLine, strComma, intLength)
Next
strText = strText & strLine & vbCrLf
Loop

objFile.Close

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\SQL DATA FILES\MBS Stats\mbsfinal\mbsfact102013_delimited.txt", ForWriting)
objFile.Write strText
objFile.Close
```

Comment: Except that every time you insert a comma, all the indices after that shift by one. Did you take this into account when constructing `arrComma`s? I would also open the output file and write the lines as soon as you are done processing. If the input file is big, you will use way more memory than needed. That being said, how does this not do what you want? Do you get an error? An unexpected result? ... Please be more specific.

Comment: The file that it is supposed to write to is still blank. Also, I thought that the strComma - 1 that is placed in the do loop took the shift into account

Comment: Code works for me. Does your code perhaps contain an `On Error Resume Next` that you didn't show? Because that would mask any error you're getting (like failing to create a non-existing output file).

Comment: No my code is exactly as posted. I don't know if this helps but it worked once earlier, and the vertical bars were in the wrong places, so I simply changed the values in the arrCommas. After re-saving and running it again, no result.

Comment: If you use **cscript.exe** to parse the vbs file, try put in `wscript.echo` line to display contents of `strLine` both before and inside For loop.

Answer (score -1):

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

arrCommas =  Array(10,14,21,24,39,43,46,61,72,79,82,85,88,91,94,97,101,142,173,189,192,198,205,211,218,222,229,236,240)

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\SQL DATA FILES\MBS Stats\mbsedited\mbsfact102013_linebreaks.txt", ForReading)

strTextFile = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close

aTextFile = Split(strTextFile, vbCRLF)

strText = ""
For Each strLine In aTextFile
    intLength = Len(strLine)
    For Each strComma in arrCommas
        strLine = Left(strLine, strComma - 1) + "|" + Mid(strLine, strComma, intLength)
    Next
    strText = strText & strLine & vbCrLf
Next

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\SQL DATA FILES\MBS Stats\mbsfinal\mbsfact102013_delimited.txt", ForWriting)
objFile.Write strText
objFile.Close
```

Comment: -1 for concatening into strText and writing strTextFile to the output file.

Comment: You know you can edit posts and not just downvote them, correct?